# why Host command returns SERVFAIL

Tags: linux, dns, host-name-resolution

I tried to use host command for my blog jfeatures.com and getting error (SERVFAIL). I am using google domains for the blog and it is powered by github pages.

```
$ host jfeatures.com
jfeatures.com has address 185.199.111.153
jfeatures.com has address 185.199.108.153
jfeatures.com has address 185.199.109.153
jfeatures.com has address 185.199.110.153
```

> Host jfeatures.com not found: 2(SERVFAIL)

```
jfeatures.com mail is handled by 20 alt2.gmr-smtp-in.l.google.com.
jfeatures.com mail is handled by 40 alt4.gmr-smtp-in.l.google.com.
jfeatures.com mail is handled by 5 gmr-smtp-in.l.google.com.
jfeatures.com mail is handled by 10 alt1.gmr-smtp-in.l.google.com.
jfeatures.com mail is handled by 30 alt3.gmr-smtp-in.l.google.com.
alt2.gmr-smtp-in.l.google.com has address 142.250.141.14
alt4.gmr-smtp-in.l.google.com has address 64.233.171.14
gmr-smtp-in.l.google.com has address 142.251.10.14
alt1.gmr-smtp-in.l.google.com has address 173.194.202.14
alt3.gmr-smtp-in.l.google.com has address 142.250.115.14
```

If I specify the DNS server, it seems to work as expected. Following is result of `host jfeatures.com 8.8.8.8`

```
host jfeatures.com 8.8.8.8
Using domain server:
Name: 8.8.8.8
Address: 8.8.8.8#53
Aliases:

jfeatures.com has address 185.199.109.153
jfeatures.com has address 185.199.111.153
jfeatures.com has address 185.199.110.153
jfeatures.com has address 185.199.108.153
jfeatures.com mail is handled by 10 alt1.gmr-smtp-in.l.google.com.
jfeatures.com mail is handled by 30 alt3.gmr-smtp-in.l.google.com.
jfeatures.com mail is handled by 40 alt4.gmr-smtp-in.l.google.com.
jfeatures.com mail is handled by 5 gmr-smtp-in.l.google.com.
jfeatures.com mail is handled by 20 alt2.gmr-smtp-in.l.google.com.
```

Comment: It's this consistently repeatable? I can't get similar behaviour here

Comment: @roaima yes for me it is consistent behavior

Comment: I checked this for stackoverflow.com as well and I see similar problem.
Works fine for google.com but google.co.in shows similar error.

Comment: OK, let's try to partition the problem. Does it fail when you specify the DNS server, for example `host jfeatures.com 8.8.8.8`? What about replacing `8.8.8.8` with `1.1.1.1` and then `9.9.9.9`?

Comment: host jfeatures.com 8.8.8.8 works perfectly fine, I have updated question with its output.

Answer (score 0):

With the extra parameter on the `host` command you're bypassing your default DNS servers defined through `/etc/resolv.conf` and specifically using the one you've provided:

```
host jfeatures.com 8.8.8.8    # {domain} {dns_server}
```

Seeing as you cannot reproduce the problem when specifying the upstream DNS server (`1.1.1.1`, `8.8.8.8`, or `9.9.9.9` as confirmed working alternatives), I'd suggest it's your upstream DNS servers that are at fault.

At home, it would be either your localhost or your ISP's own servers. At work it would typically be your network's DNS servers. Depending on how far you want to get involved in identifying the faulty component you can work through the chain of DNS servers. For example, if `/etc/resolv.conf` contains a reference to `nameserver 127.0.0.53` you're using `systemd-resolved` and you need to check `/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf` for details of your upstream DNS servers. Otherwise use the values in `/etc/resolv.conf` itself.